Gitlab Access Token Issue
Here's detailed explanation of the problem:

I have a gitlab account: user
I created a private repo in it:repo-1 and did npm publish.
In the package.json, i made the name as @user/repo-1 ( scoped it )
I created an access token and gave it full permission and role was developer.
I created another private repo: repo-2 and repo-3.
Both of these are private and their access token are developer role with full permission.
Now I went back to repo-1 and changed the token and project id in its npmrc file with repo-2 project id and auth token as well as in the publishConfig in package.json and changed the package-name and did npm publish, now this published repo-1 to repo-2 with the updated version.

Now my problem is, if i am trying to install repo-1 with the auth token of repo-1, it should work which is working but if i try to install the updated repo-1 which i published to repo-2 using the auth token of repo-1 then also it is installing
why this happen?

Read docs of gitlab and npm and nowhere this problem is mentioned

